# Vue.js - Error when displaying base64 image strings (431, request header field too large)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

we are encountering this error where we try to display a base64 string from the backend using the following code:
[Our code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWxya.png)

```
<img v-bind:src="`data:image/jpg;base64,${atob(photo.path)}`"

<img v-bind:src="data:image/jpg;base64,${photo.path}"
```

Where photo.path == \x13r23p9rd0823hr4c9fnp23h4n-9f8c2hn438hf293hfpweu9fhpweiufnwe

We just constantly encounter a 431 request header field too large error (screenshot attached below).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[Our error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZnvi.png)

Comment: that's odd ... why is it making a request to the server?

Comment: Can you show how `img` is look like in browser dev tools?